# xpages message box before logging out

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have the following code logging out the user from app and "send" him back to the session based authentication page ( [Thanks Paul Withers](http://www.intec.co.uk/sessions-logout-sessionscope-and-userscope/) ):

```
 clearing_function(sessionScope); 

 var appUrl = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
 var url = appUrl + "?logout&redirectto=" + appUrl;
 facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Is there any chance to have like a `@prompt` formula with yes/no and just in case if user selects yes the above code ( from ssjs ) to be executed? Or I must write the confirmation message in csjs. But, then, how can I transform the above code in csjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dialog component from extension library to build a confirmation box with two buttons where the positive button runs your logout code

```
    <xe:dialog id="dialog1">
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:button value="OK" id="button1">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:clearing_function(sessionScope); 

             var appUrl = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
             var url = appUrl + "?logout&redirectto=" + appUrl;
             facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);}]]></xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
                <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button2">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dialog1">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").hide();}]]>   </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:panel>
    </xe:dialog>
```

To hide the default x button just override the relevant css classes:

for oneui themes it's the "lotusBtnImg" class
for webstandard it's the ".dijitDialogCloseIcon" class

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think at <xe:dialog>. i will give a try and let you know

Comment: Is there any chance to hide the X dialog button?

Comment: Use css with .lotusBtnImg{visibility: hidden;}

Comment: But how can I select the button from source or design? It is like as a default button for the dialog

Comment: .lotusBtnImg is the default class you can override.

Comment: I create already the css class but where to add it in the dialog?

Comment: If you use an oneui theme in Xpage properties it's the class that is bind to the x dialog button. You only have to use the style class in css stylesheet

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap theme

Comment: Have you checked in browser which style class is used from bootstrap theme to display the x dialog button? This class you have to override

Comment: I think simple CSJS confirm() method would do the trick without complex dialog coding.